# Include custom attribute on Facebook registration

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-attribute, facebook

I need to save custom attribute(Customer) values on registration for normal registration I'm using POST method, But how can I implement the same for facebook registration.

> **Registration with custom attributes**

```
<?php

require_once('../app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app();


 if (isset($_POST['loginStatus']))
 {



     $loginStatus =$_POST['loginStatus']; //get login status
     $customerId =$_POST['customerId']; //get customer id

     $getStylistId =$_POST['getStylistId']; //get stylist id


     $customerFirstName =$_POST['registerFirstname']; //get customer fname
     $customerLastName =$_POST['registerLastname']; //get customer lname
     $customerEmail =$_POST['registerEmail']; //get customer email
     $customerPassword =$_POST['registerPassword1']; //get customer password  



     $get_Gender =$_POST['get_Gender']; //get gender
     $styles =$_POST['styles']; //get preffered style
     $daring =$_POST['daring']; //get how daring value
     $weekdayStyle = $_POST['weekdayStyle']; //weekday style
     $weekendStyle = $_POST['weekendStyle']; //weekend style
     $nightoutStyle = $_POST['nightoutStyle']; //nightout style
     $bodytypeStyle = $_POST['bodytypeStyle']; //body style

     $showoffLegsStyle = $_POST['showoffLegsStyle']; //(showoff/ cover up) Legs
     $showoffChestStyle = $_POST['showoffChestStyle']; //(showoff/ cover up) Chest
     $showoffArmsStyle = $_POST['showoffArmsStyle']; //(showoff/ cover up) Arms
     $showoffStomachStyle = $_POST['showoffStomachStyle']; //(showoff/ cover up) Stomach

     $skinType =$_POST['skinType']; //Skin type
     $age =$_POST['age']; //age
     $heightFeet =$_POST['heightFeet']; //height feet
     $heightInches =$_POST['heightInches']; //height inches

     $topSize =$_POST['topSize']; //Top size
     $waistSize =$_POST['waistSize']; //Waist size
     $shoeSize =$_POST['showSize']; //Shoe size
     $jacketSize =$_POST['jacketSize']; //Jacket size

     $spendDress =$_POST['spendDress']; //Spend for Dress
     $spendCoatJacket =$_POST['spendCoatJacket']; //Spend for coat&jacket
     $spendBlazzers =$_POST['spendBlazzers']; //Spend for Blazzers
     $spendBags =$_POST['spendBags']; //Spend for Bags
     $spendShoes =$_POST['spendShoes']; //Spend for Shoes
     $spendBasics =$_POST['spendBasics']; //Spend for Basics
     $spendDenim =$_POST['spendDenim']; //Spend for Denim

     $spendGym =$_POST['spendGym']; //Spend for Gym
     $spendPants =$_POST['spendPants']; //Spend for Pants
     $spendSweater =$_POST['spendSweater']; //Spend for Sweater




     $preffBrands =$_POST['preffBrands']; //Preffered Brands
     $lookSpecific =$_POST['lookSpecific']; //Specific look








     $getStyleValues = "";
     $getWeekdayStyleValues = "";
     $getWeekendStyleValues = "";
     $getNightoutStyleValues = "";
     $getBodytypeStyleValues = "";
     $getBrandtype = "";





             /*Gender selection*/
             if($get_Gender == 'Womenswear')
             {
                $gender = 2;
             }
             else{
                $gender = 1;
             }



    if($loginStatus == 1)
    {

        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);


            /*Style Iteration*/
            for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($styles); $i++) { 

                //echo "\nStyles: ".$styles[$i];
                $attr_styles = 'style_preffered'; //attr code of preffered style.
                $attr_styles = $customer->getResource()->getAttribute($attr_styles);
                if ($attr_styles->usesSource()) {
                echo "\nPreffered Style Id: ".$style_id = $attr_styles->getSource()->getOptionId($styles[$i]);

                $getStyleValues = $getStyleValues.$style_id.', ';
                }
            }

            /*Weekday Style Iteration*/
            for ($j=0; $j < sizeof($weekdayStyle); $j++) { 

                //echo "\nWeekday styles: ".$weekdayStyle[$j];
                $attr_weekday = 'weekday_style'; //attr code of preffered style.
                $attr_weekday = $customer->getResource()->getAttribute($attr_weekday);
                if ($attr_weekday->usesSource()) {
                echo "\nWeekday Style Id: ".$weekdayStyle_id = $attr_weekday->getSource()->getOptionId($weekdayStyle[$j]);

                $getWeekdayStyleValues = $getWeekdayStyleValues.$weekdayStyle_id.', ';
                }
            }

            /*Weekend Style Iteration*/
            for ($k=0; $k < sizeof($weekendStyle); $k++) { 

                //echo "\nWeekday styles: ".$weekendStyle[$k];
                $attr_weekend = 'weekend_style'; //attr code of preffered style.
                $attr_weekend = $customer->getResource()->getAttribute($attr_weekend);
                if ($attr_weekend->usesSource()) {
                echo "\nWeekend Style Id: ".$weekendStyle_id = $attr_weekend->getSource()->getOptionId($weekendStyle[$k]);

                $getWeekendStyleValues = $getWeekendStyleValues.$weekendStyle_id.', ';
                }
            }

            /*Nightout Style Iteration*/
            for ($l=0; $l < sizeof($nightoutStyle); $l++) { 

                //echo "\nWeekday styles: ".$nightoutStyle[$l];
                $attr_nightout = 'nightout_style'; //attr code of preffered style.
                $attr_nightout = $customer->getResource()->getAttribute($attr_nightout);
                if ($attr_nightout->usesSource()) {
                echo "\nNightout Style Id: ".$nightoutStyle_id = $attr_nightout->getSource()->getOptionId($nightoutStyle[$l]);

                $getNightoutStyleValues = $getNightoutStyleValues.$nightoutStyle_id.', ';
                }
            }

            //$bodytypeStyle

            /*Body Type Style Iteration*/
            for ($m=0; $m < sizeof($bodytypeStyle); $m++) { 

                //echo "\nWeekday styles: ".$bodytypeStyle[$m];
                $attr_bodytype = 'body_type'; //attr code of preffered style.
                $attr_bodytype = $customer->getResource()->getAttribute($attr_bodytype);
                if ($attr_bodytype->usesSource()) {
                echo "\nBody Type Style Id: ".$bodytypeStyle_id = $attr_bodytype->getSource()->getOptionId($bodytypeStyle[$m]);

                $getBodytypeStyleValues = $getBodytypeStyleValues.$bodytypeStyle_id.', ';
                }
            }


            //showoff_arms
            /*Show off ARMS*/
            if($showoffArmsStyle != "")
            {
                $attr_showoffArms = 'showoff_arms'; //attr code of preffered style.
                $attr_showoffArms = $customer->getResource()->getAttribute($attr_showoffArms);
                if ($attr_showoffArms->usesSource()) {
                echo "\nArms Showoff Style Id: ".$armsShowoffType_Id = $attr_showoffArms->getSource()->getOptionId($showoffArmsStyle);

                $armsShowoffType = $armsShowoffType_Id;
                }
            }
            /*Show off LEGS*/
            if($showoffLegsStyle != "")
            {
                $attr_showoffLegs = 'showoff_legs'; //attr code of preffered style.
                $attr_showoffLegs = $customer->getResource()->getAttribute($attr_showoffLegs);
                if ($attr_showoffLegs->usesSource()) {
                echo "\nLegs Showoff Style Id: ".$legsShowoffType_Id = $attr_showoffLegs->getSource()->getOptionId($showoffLegsStyle);

                $legsShowoffType = $legsShowoffType_Id;
                }
            }
            /*Show off CHEST*/
            if($showoffChestStyle != "")
            {
                $attr_showoffChest = 'showoff_chest'; //attr code of preffered style.
                $attr_showoffChest = $customer->getResource()->getAttribute($attr_showoffChest);
                if ($attr_showoffChest->usesSource()) {
                echo "\nChest Showoff Style Id: ".$chestShowoffType_Id = $attr_showoffChest->getSource()->getOptionId($showoffChestStyle);

                $chestShowoffType = $chestShowoffType_Id;
                }
            }
            /*Show off STOMACH*/
            if($showoffStomachStyle != "")
            {
                $attr_showoffStomach = 'showoff_stomach'; //attr code of preffered style.
                $attr_showoffStomach = $customer->getResource()->getAttribute($attr_showoffStomach);
                if ($attr_showoffStomach->usesSource()) {
                echo "\nStomach Showoff Style Id: ".$stomachShowoffType_Id = $attr_showoffStomach->getSource()->getOptionId($showoffStomachStyle);

                $stomachShowoffType = $stomachShowoffType_Id;
                }
            }



            /*top size*/
                $attr_topSize = 'top_size'; //attr code of preffered style.
                $attr_topSize = $customer->getResource()->getAttribute($attr_topSize);
                if ($attr_topSize->usesSource()) {
                echo "\nTop size Id: ".$topSize_Id = $attr_topSize->getSource()->getOptionId($topSize);

                }


            /*waist size*/
                $attr_waistSize = 'waist_size'; //attr code of preffered style.
                $attr_waistSize = $customer->getResource()->getAttribute($attr_waistSize);
                if ($attr_waistSize->usesSource()) {
                echo "\nWaist size Id: ".$waistSize_Id = $attr_waistSize->getSource()->getOptionId($waistSize);

                }


            /*shoe size*/
                $attr_shoeSize = 'show_size'; //attr code of preffered style.
                $attr_shoeSize = $customer->getResource()->getAttribute($attr_shoeSize);
                if ($attr_shoeSize->usesSource()) {
                echo "\nShoe size Id: ".$shoeSize_Id = $attr_shoeSize->getSource()->getOptionId($shoeSize);

                }

            /*Jacket size*/
                $attr_jacketSize = 'jacket_size'; //attr code of preffered style.
                $attr_jacketSize = $customer->getResource()->getAttribute($attr_jacketSize);
                if ($attr_jacketSize->usesSource()) {
                echo "\nJacket size Id: ".$jacketSize_Id = $attr_jacketSize->getSource()->getOptionId($jacketSize);

                }



            /*Brands*/
            for ($n=0; $n < sizeof($preffBrands); $n++) { 

                //echo "\nWeekday styles: ".$preffBrands[$n];
                $attr_brand = 'follow_brands'; //attr code of preffered style.
                $attr_brand = $customer->getResource()->getAttribute($attr_brand);
                if ($attr_brand->usesSource()) {
                echo "\nBrand Id: ".$preffBrands_id = $attr_brand->getSource()->getOptionId($preffBrands[$n]);

                $getBrandtype = $getBrandtype.$preffBrands_id.', ';
                }
            }



        /*Saving Datas for logged in customer*/

        $customer->setData('gender',$gender); //set gender
        $customer->setData('style_preffered', $getStyleValues); //set style preffered
        $customer->setData('daring_look', $daring); //daring look
        $customer->setData('weekday_style', $getWeekdayStyleValues); //weekday style
        $customer->setData('weekend_style', $getWeekendStyleValues); //weekend style
        $customer->setData('nightout_style', $getNightoutStyleValues); //nightout style
        $customer->setData('body_type', $getBodytypeStyleValues); //body type style

        $customer->setData('showoff_arms', $armsShowoffType); //body type style
        $customer->setData('showoff_legs', $legsShowoffType); //body type style
        $customer->setData('showoff_chest', $chestShowoffType); //body type style
        $customer->setData('showoff_stomach', $stomachShowoffType); //body type style

        $customer->setData('skin_color', $skinType); //Skin type
        $customer->setData('age', $age); //Age
        $customer->setData('h_ft', $heightFeet); //Height feet
        $customer->setData('h_inches', $heightInches); //Height inches

        $customer->setData('top_size', $topSize_Id); //Top Size
        $customer->setData('waist_size', $waistSize_Id); //Waist Size
        $customer->setData('show_size', $shoeSize_Id); //Show Size
        $customer->setData('jacket_size', $jacketSize_Id); //Jacket Size

        $customer->setData('spend_goingout_dress', $spendDress); //Spend Dresses
        $customer->setData('spend_coat_jacket', $spendCoatJacket); //Spend Jackets
        $customer->setData('spend_blazzers', $spendBlazzers); //Spend Blazzers
        $customer->setData('spend_handbags', $spendBags); //Spend Bags
        $customer->setData('spend_shoes', $spendShoes); //Spend Shoes
        $customer->setData('spend_basics', $spendBasics); //Spend Basics
        $customer->setData('spend_denim', $spendDenim); //SpendDenim

        $customer->setData('spend_gymwear', $spendGym); //SpendGym
        $customer->setData('spend_pants_trousers', $spendPants); //SpendPants
        $customer->setData('spend_sweaters_cardigans', $spendSweater); //SpendSweater




        $customer->setData('follow_brands', $getBrandtype); //Brands
        $customer->setData('specific_look', $lookSpecific); //Specific Look

        $customer->setData('stylist_id', $getStylistId); //Stylist Id




        try {
            $customer->save();
            echo "\nSuccess";
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            echo "\nerror";
        }
        /*//////////////////////////////////////*/
    }

    else{
        //echo "\nCUSTOMMER LOGGED OUT";
        $websiteId = Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId();
        $store = Mage::app()->getStore();
        $customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");


        $customer   ->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
            ->setStore($store)
            ->setFirstname($customerFirstName)
            ->setLastname($customerLastName)
            ->setEmail($customerEmail)
            ->setPassword($customerPassword);


            /*Style Iteration*/
            for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($styles); $i++) { 

                //echo "\nStyles: ".$styles[$i];
                $attr_styles = 'style_preffered'; //attr code of preffered style.
                $attr_styles = $customer->getResource()->getAttribute($attr_styles);
                if ($attr_styles->usesSource()) {
                echo "\nPreffered Style Id: ".$style_id = $attr_styles->getSource()->getOptionId($styles[$i]);

                $getStyleValues = $getStyleValues.$style_id.', ';
                }
            }

            /*Weekday Style Iteration*/
            for ($j=0; $j < sizeof($weekdayStyle); $j++) { 

                //echo "\nWeekday styles: ".$weekdayStyle[$j];
                $attr_weekday = 'weekday_style'; //attr code of preffered style.
                $attr_weekday = $customer->getResource()->getAttribute($attr_weekday);
                if ($attr_weekday->usesSource()) {
                echo "\nWeekday Style Id: ".$weekdayStyle_id = $attr_weekday->getSource()->getOptionId($weekdayStyle[$j]);

                $getWeekdayStyleValues = $getWeekdayStyleValues.$weekdayStyle_id.', ';
                }
            }

            /*Weekend Style Iteration*/
            for ($k=0; $k < sizeof($weekendStyle); $k++) { 

                //echo "\nWeekday styles: ".$weekendStyle[$k];
                $attr_weekend = 'weekend_style'; //attr code of preffered style.
                $attr_weekend = $customer->getResource()->getAttribute($attr_weekend);
                if ($attr_weekend->usesSource()) {
                echo "\nWeekend Style Id: ".$weekendStyle_id = $attr_weekend->getSource()->getOptionId($weekendStyle[$k]);

                $getWeekendStyleValues = $getWeekendStyleValues.$weekendStyle_id.', ';
                }
            }

            /*Nightout Style Iteration*/
            for ($l=0; $l < sizeof($nightoutStyle); $l++) { 

                //echo "\nWeekday styles: ".$nightoutStyle[$l];
                $attr_nightout = 'nightout_style'; //attr code of preffered style.
                $attr_nightout = $customer->getResource()->getAttribute($attr_nightout);
                if ($attr_nightout->usesSource()) {
                echo "\nNightout Style Id: ".$nightoutStyle_id = $attr_nightout->getSource()->getOptionId($nightoutStyle[$l]);

                $getNightoutStyleValues = $getNightoutStyleValues.$nightoutStyle_id.', ';
                }
            }

            //$bodytypeStyle

            /*Body Type Style Iteration*/
            for ($m=0; $m < sizeof($bodytypeStyle); $m++) { 

                //echo "\nWeekday styles: ".$bodytypeStyle[$m];
                $attr_bodytype = 'body_type'; //attr code of preffered style.
                $attr_bodytype = $customer->getResource()->getAttribute($attr_bodytype);
                if ($attr_bodytype->usesSource()) {
                echo "\nBody Type Style Id: ".$bodytypeStyle_id = $attr_bodytype->getSource()->getOptionId($bodytypeStyle[$m]);

                $getBodytypeStyleValues = $getBodytypeStyleValues.$bodytypeStyle_id.', ';
                }
            }


            //showoff_arms
            /*Show off ARMS*/
            if($showoffArmsStyle != "")
            {
                $attr_showoffArms = 'showoff_arms'; //attr code of preffered style.
                $attr_showoffArms = $customer->getResource()->getAttribute($attr_showoffArms);
                if ($attr_showoffArms->usesSource()) {
                echo "\nArms Showoff Style Id: ".$armsShowoffType_Id = $attr_showoffArms->getSource()->getOptionId($showoffArmsStyle);

                $armsShowoffType = $armsShowoffType_Id;
                }
            }
            /*Show off LEGS*/
            if($showoffLegsStyle != "")
            {
                $attr_showoffLegs = 'showoff_legs'; //attr code of preffered style.
                $attr_showoffLegs = $customer->getResource()->getAttribute($attr_showoffLegs);
                if ($attr_showoffLegs->usesSource()) {
                echo "\nLegs Showoff Style Id: ".$legsShowoffType_Id = $attr_showoffLegs->getSource()->getOptionId($showoffLegsStyle);

                $legsShowoffType = $legsShowoffType_Id;
                }
            }
            /*Show off CHEST*/
            if($showoffChestStyle != "")
            {
                $attr_showoffChest = 'showoff_chest'; //attr code of preffered style.
                $attr_showoffChest = $customer->getResource()->getAttribute($attr_showoffChest);
                if ($attr_showoffChest->usesSource()) {
                echo "\nChest Showoff Style Id: ".$chestShowoffType_Id = $attr_showoffChest->getSource()->getOptionId($showoffChestStyle);

                $chestShowoffType = $chestShowoffType_Id;
                }
            }
            /*Show off STOMACH*/
            if($showoffStomachStyle != "")
            {
                $attr_showoffStomach = 'showoff_stomach'; //attr code of preffered style.
                $attr_showoffStomach = $customer->getResource()->getAttribute($attr_showoffStomach);
                if ($attr_showoffStomach->usesSource()) {
                echo "\nStomach Showoff Style Id: ".$stomachShowoffType_Id = $attr_showoffStomach->getSource()->getOptionId($showoffStomachStyle);

                $stomachShowoffType = $stomachShowoffType_Id;
                }
            }



            /*top size*/
                $attr_topSize = 'top_size'; //attr code of preffered style.
                $attr_topSize = $customer->getResource()->getAttribute($attr_topSize);
                if ($attr_topSize->usesSource()) {
                echo "\nTop size Id: ".$topSize_Id = $attr_topSize->getSource()->getOptionId($topSize);

                }


            /*waist size*/
                $attr_waistSize = 'waist_size'; //attr code of preffered style.
                $attr_waistSize = $customer->getResource()->getAttribute($attr_waistSize);
                if ($attr_waistSize->usesSource()) {
                echo "\nWaist size Id: ".$waistSize_Id = $attr_waistSize->getSource()->getOptionId($waistSize);

                }


            /*shoe size*/
                $attr_shoeSize = 'show_size'; //attr code of preffered style.
                $attr_shoeSize = $customer->getResource()->getAttribute($attr_shoeSize);
                if ($attr_shoeSize->usesSource()) {
                echo "\nShoe size Id: ".$shoeSize_Id = $attr_shoeSize->getSource()->getOptionId($shoeSize);

                }

            /*Jacket size*/
                $attr_jacketSize = 'jacket_size'; //attr code of preffered style.
                $attr_jacketSize = $customer->getResource()->getAttribute($attr_jacketSize);
                if ($attr_jacketSize->usesSource()) {
                echo "\nJacket size Id: ".$jacketSize_Id = $attr_jacketSize->getSource()->getOptionId($jacketSize);

                }



            /*Brands*/
            for ($n=0; $n < sizeof($preffBrands); $n++) { 

                //echo "\nWeekday styles: ".$preffBrands[$n];
                $attr_brand = 'follow_brands'; //attr code of preffered style.
                $attr_brand = $customer->getResource()->getAttribute($attr_brand);
                if ($attr_brand->usesSource()) {
                echo "\nBrand Id: ".$preffBrands_id = $attr_brand->getSource()->getOptionId($preffBrands[$n]);

                $getBrandtype = $getBrandtype.$preffBrands_id.', ';
                }
            }



        /*Saving Datas for logged in customer*/

        $customer->setData('gender',$gender); //set gender
        $customer->setData('style_preffered', $getStyleValues); //set style preffered
        $customer->setData('daring_look', $daring); //daring look
        $customer->setData('weekday_style', $getWeekdayStyleValues); //weekday style
        $customer->setData('weekend_style', $getWeekendStyleValues); //weekend style
        $customer->setData('nightout_style', $getNightoutStyleValues); //nightout style
        $customer->setData('body_type', $getBodytypeStyleValues); //body type style

        $customer->setData('showoff_arms', $armsShowoffType); //body type style
        $customer->setData('showoff_legs', $legsShowoffType); //body type style
        $customer->setData('showoff_chest', $chestShowoffType); //body type style
        $customer->setData('showoff_stomach', $stomachShowoffType); //body type style

        $customer->setData('skin_color', $skinType); //Skin type
        $customer->setData('age', $age); //Age
        $customer->setData('h_ft', $heightFeet); //Height feet
        $customer->setData('h_inches', $heightInches); //Height inches

        $customer->setData('top_size', $topSize_Id); //Top Size
        $customer->setData('waist_size', $waistSize_Id); //Waist Size
        $customer->setData('show_size', $shoeSize_Id); //Show Size
        $customer->setData('jacket_size', $jacketSize_Id); //Jacket Size

        $customer->setData('spend_goingout_dress', $spendDress); //Spend Dresses
        $customer->setData('spend_coat_jacket', $spendCoatJacket); //Spend Jackets
        $customer->setData('spend_blazzers', $spendBlazzers); //Spend Blazzers
        $customer->setData('spend_handbags', $spendBags); //Spend Bags
        $customer->setData('spend_shoes', $spendShoes); //Spend Shoes
        $customer->setData('spend_basics', $spendBasics); //Spend Basics
        $customer->setData('spend_denim', $spendDenim); //SpendDenim

        $customer->setData('spend_gymwear', $spendGym); //SpendGym
        $customer->setData('spend_pants_trousers', $spendPants); //SpendPants
        $customer->setData('spend_sweaters_cardigans', $spendSweater); //SpendSweater




        $customer->setData('follow_brands', $getBrandtype); //Brands
        $customer->setData('specific_look', $lookSpecific); //Specific Look

        $customer->setData('stylist_id', $getStylistId); //Stylist Id


        try {
            $customer->save();
            echo "\nSuccess";
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            echo "\nerror";
        }


    }

  }
```

> **Facebook Registration**

```
protected function createCustomerMultiWebsite($data, $website_id, $store_id)
    {
        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->setId(null);
        $customer ->setFirstname($data['firstname'])
                    ->setLastname($data['lastname'])
                    ->setEmail($data['email'])
                    ->setWebsiteId($website_id)
                    ->setStoreId($store_id)
                    ->save()

                    ;
        $isSendPassToCustomer = Mage::getStoreConfig('fblogin/general/is_send_password_to_customer');
        $newPassword = $customer->generatePassword();
        $customer->setPassword($newPassword);
        try{
            $customer->save();
        }catch(Exception $e){}

        if($isSendPassToCustomer)
            $customer->sendPasswordReminderEmail();
        return $customer;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what a facebook registration is, because it's not in the core, but most probably you should take a look at how the `$data` variable looks. Maybe you find what you need in there.
Something like:

```
$customer->setFirstname($data['firstname'])
         ->setLastname($data['lastname'])
         ->setEmail($data['email'])
         ->setWebsiteId($website_id)
         ->setStoreId($store_id)
         ->setData('age', $data['age']) //do this for all elements you have in $data
         ->save()
```